# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Stan does not support NA (in t) in data

Tags: r, stan

I am trying to implement facebook's new prophet api in R when i faced this issue. The code is below

```
    library(prophet)
    library(dplyr)
    df <- read.csv('.../Peyton_Manning.csv') %>%
    mutate(y = log(y))
    m <- prophet(df)
```

At this line i am getting the below error

```
    Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Stan does not support NA (in t) in data
    failed to preprocess the data; optimization not done
   Show Traceback
    Error in matrix(m$params[[name]], nrow = n.iteration) : 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem although my dataset doesn't contain any NA value.
The problem was about one of the variables that I defined as an integer while it should be real as it is a continuous variable. Thus, I changed it to real and the problem has been solved!